# Hadoop job not running in pseudodistributed mode

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins, hadoop-2.7.2

When i run jps output is as follows

`siu@siu-pc:~/project$ jps
6994 Jps
5365 ResourceManager
4902 DataNode
4330 DataNode
4829 DataNode
5616 NodeManager
4681 SecondaryNameNode
6684 RunJar
4997 DataNode
5092 DataNode
4077 NameNode`

When the hadoop job is run output is

`16/05/24 15:52:01 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/05/24 15:52:02 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at localhost/127.0.0.1:8032
16/05/24 15:52:03 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/05/24 15:52:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/05/24 15:52:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1464084094270_0003
16/05/24 15:52:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1464084094270_0003
16/05/24 15:52:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://siu-pc:8088/proxy/application_1464084094270_0003/
16/05/24 15:52:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1464084094270_0003`

and this doesn't get completed even after hours

Comment: Please post job logs

Comment: Looks like your ResourceManager doesn't have enough resources to run your job. Look at YARN UI web page (port 8088) and check number of available cores and memory. If free resources available then check logs of your job and YARN settings (in yarn-site.xml file)

Comment: I am new to hadoop will you please explain in detail what settings need to be checked@maxteneff

Comment: All job logs??@Krishna Chaitanya Reddy